# Get data from multiples SharePoint library's in multiple sites

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery

I want to extract information from multiple SharePoint libraries that are located in different SharePoint sites collection.

All libraries in the same name have the same structure. I'm getting an error that is nor possible to convert the value “Library1” to the type List.

I'm using the following script:

```
let
    sitesEBibliotecas = {
        {"https://Site1", {"Library1", "Library2"}},
        {"https://Site2", {"Library1", "Library2"}}
    },

    tabelasDeBibliotecas = List.Combine(
        List.Transform(
            sitesEBibliotecas,
            each List.Combine(
                List.Transform(
                    _{1},
                    each let
                        biblioteca = _,
                        Origem = SharePoint.Tables(_{0} & "/" & biblioteca, [ApiVersion = 15]),
                        lista = Origem{[Id=biblioteca]}[Items]
                    in
                        lista
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    tabelasDeBibliotecas1 = tabelasDeBibliotecas{0}
in
    tabelasDeBibliotecas1
```

Comment: Please paste code as text and not as an image. Edit your question to include the code so others can copy'n'paste etc...

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on that list structure then you want something similar to below

```
let
sitesEBibliotecas = {
    {"https://Site1", {"Library1", "Library2"}},
    {"https://Site2", {"Library1", "Library2"}}
},
hitlist= Table.FromList(List.Combine(List.Transform(sitesEBibliotecas, each  let a=_ in List.Transform (a{1}, each a{0}& "/" &_ )))),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(hitlist, "Output", each SharePoint.Tables([Column1]))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This bit `SharePoint.Tables(_{0}` is causing the issue. Updated your query to store the site name in a variable.

```
let
  sitesEBibliotecas = {
    {"https://Site1", {"Library1", "Library2"}},
    {"https://Site2", {"Library1", "Library2"}}
  },

  tabelasDeBibliotecas = List.Combine(
    List.Transform(
        sitesEBibliotecas,
        each let
          site = _{0},
          libraries = _{1},
          combined =  List.Combine(
            List.Transform(
              libraries,
              each let
                biblioteca = _,
                Origem = SharePoint.Tables(site & "/" & biblioteca, [ApiVersion = 15]),
                lista = Origem{[Id=biblioteca]}[Items]
              in
                lista
            )
          )
        in combined
    )
  ),
  tabelasDeBibliotecas1 = tabelasDeBibliotecas{0}
in
  tabelasDeBibliotecas1
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?